# Can I shorten/Clean up this code

Tags: php

I am really annoyed by having this much IF, Else If statements.... Is there a way to shorten this up and make it look cleaner, nicer but still have the same effect?

```
if(!empty($ck1))
{
    $ck1 = 'Tiger';
}
else
{
    $ck1 = '';
}


if(!empty($ck2))
{
    $ck2 = 'Bears';
}
else
{
    $ck2 = '';
}
if(!empty($ck3))
{
    $ck3 = 'Owls';
}
else
{
    $ck3 = '';
}
```

Comment: Use like this: `$ck1 = !empty($ck1)?'Tiger':''`

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: how many `ck`s you have? are you vars named just `ckX`? or can be anything?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski 36, all $ck+number   1-36

Comment: Where do all those `$ckX` variables come from to begin with?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Check boxes on a form.

Comment: There you go. You should be able to make the check box values equal to 'Tiger', 'Bears', etc.

Comment: Can you edit the question to show a couple of examples of your form inputs, and the PHP code used to populate the `$ck` variables? I really think that will be the simplest way to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that perhaps is cleanest, assuming you need different default values.

```
$vars = array(
    'ck1' => 'Tiger',
    'ck2' => 'Owl',
    ...
    'ck36' => 'Foo'
    );
foreach($vars as $var=>$default) {
    $$var = !empty($$var) ? $default : '';
}
```

You can use `for` and build `$var` dynamically, but it'd be painful to deal with  default values (especially edits would lead to errors, sooner than later), so it's not worth.

**EDIT**

`$vars` array holds variable name you want to work on as key, and default value as value. So you can have as many as you like there.

**EDIT 2**

Beware of variable scopes. Also you said that `ck`s come from `Check boxes on a form`. If so, then it means you got `register_globals` enabled? If so, it's bad idea and you should disable it ASAP.

**EDIT 3**

Instead of having tons of variables, you should keep them organized as array, by using `[]` in variable name tag:

```
<input name="ck[]" value="Foo">
<input name="ck[]" value="Bar">
```

then **all** inputs (in case of checkbox, all checked of course) can be easily found in `$_POST['ck']`. You can also add own index if you want to then look easily for particular item:

```
<input name="ck[foo]" value="Foo">
```

is available as `$_POST['ck']['foo']`. That would allow to make your code cleaner, i.e.:

```
$input = $_POST['ck'];

$vars = array(
    'ck1 => 'Tiger',
    'ck2' => 'Owl,
    ...
    'ck36' => 'Foo'
    );
foreach($vars as $key=>$default) {
    $input[$key] = !empty($input[$key]) ? $default : '';
}
```

end then you can use `$input` further in your code, w/o having tons of variables in the script scope.

Comment: Why is register_globals a bad idea?

Comment: In short - it allows attacker to 'inject' variables int your script. Depending on your code it may do nothing bad or make you hacked. But if it does nothing bad, then you do not need it anyway. There's absolutely no need to anything but your code to be able to do that. In general google for "why php register_globals bad".

Comment: Last question, with that code though.. I have a DB that has rows ck1 - ck36... How can I tell it row ck1  = what? $input[Key]?

Comment: or ck1 = $input[ck1]?

Comment: It depends what you want to do with it later. Sometimes you can use `id` from database sometimes now (because that would i.e. expose your Ids and you do not wan to do that). The trick with checkboxes is the these are NOT sent when not checked, so you need to know which one is missing. It is irrelevant it will be `ck1` or `2342345` as long as **your code** knows what it is.

Comment: I am very confused as to how an update this in DB now. I have `INSERT INTO forms(mycheck) VALUES (:check); $stmt->bindparam(":check", $input);` When I do that and run, Int he mycheck row, it just says array

Comment: Kevin, SO is not regular discussion board. You asked about how to optimize your code - you got the result. You should accept the answer if you got your question answered (and I bet you do) and not extend the scope any further questions. If any other problem show you can ask another question. And for `bindparams()` - it binds values, but it is not query builder. So this is one problem with your code. You need code like `INSERT INTO forms(mycheck) VALUES (ck1 = ?, ck2= ?)` and then bind params (you can create loop bo build your query).

Comment: I accepted your code... FYI though... Changing to your example changed the way I insert into my table... So I figured since you made the example you would know how to insert. Ok though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ternary operators:

```
$ck1 = !empty($ck1) ? 'Tiger' : '';
$ck2 = !empty($ck2) ? 'Bears' : '';
$ck3 = !empty($ck3) ? 'Owls' : '';
```

It's still, technically, a bunch of if-statements, but it is more concise.

If you have a lot of things to reference, you could create an array and loop through it:

```
$cks = array(
  'ck1' => 'Tiger',
  'ck2' => 'Bears',
  'ck3' => 'Owls',
  ...
);
foreach($cks as $var => $value) {
  $$var = !empty($$var) ? $value : '';
}
```

Comment: @sethflowers thanks. I always forget the word for it.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps the '[switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)' statement could help you out

Comment: I looked at that too but then I would just have a tonf of switch variable right? Since I have $ck1, $ck2, $ck3 - $ck24

Comment: You asked for something cleaner and nicer...a switch statement is just that